# Que significa of dentro de un for

Tags: nodejs

Buenos días/tardes o noches. Ando practicando nodeJS y llega un momento donde el video esta corrupto/dañado y no se logra apreciar ni escuchar lo que hace la persona en el video. Cosa que, realiza ciertos códigos y hay uno en particular que no logro entender.

Me gustaría por favor que alguien me explique la razón de ese of que esta después de la tarea y antes del listado. Por que en verdad no se que significa ni por que esta dentro del ciclo for. Muchas gracias y espero ayuda!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La explicación https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Comment: Hola Yisus_Dra, bienvenido, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta, elimines las imágenes, y adjuntes tu código como texto, así evitarás recibir votos negativos.
Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando usas el `in`, la iteración se hace sobre índices:

```
for(var i in ['a', 'b', 'c'])
  console.log(i);

//resultado:
//0
//1
//2
```

```
for(var i in {'a': 1, 4: 1})
  console.log(i)

//resultado:
//a
//4
```

Cuando usas `of` (exclusivamente para listas) se itera sobre los valores:

```
for(var i of ['a', 'b', 'c'])
  console.log(i);

//resultado:
//a
//b
//c
```

Comment: Gracias, ya lo corregí.

Comment: Un pequeña aclaración el `of` opera sobre `iterables`, los `array` en JS son iterables, pero hay iterables que no son array. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_generators